# python turtle not draw

Tags: python, python-turtle

I tried to run my graphic code turtle python, but my code doesn't draw the code.

This is my code,

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, color, right, speed

def draw_square(some_turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(90)
    
def draw_art():
    brad = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.pensize(2)
    brad.speed(0)
    for _ in range(36):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)
    # Turtle Angie
    angie = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.pensize(2)
    angie.speed(0)
    size = 1
    for _ in range(300):
        angie.forward(size)
        angie.right(91)
        size += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you never called your functions to draw the turtle.
Just add:

```
draw_art()
```

At the end of your python file, and run.

Also you never made a screen that the turtle will be on. Inside `draw_art()` you need to add:

```
win = Screen()
win.mainloop() # <— last line in the function!
```

And this supposed to work. It might show you the screen just for a second and close, so you need to also add (after you call `draw_art()`) infinite `while` loop or `sleep()` method, to pause the program and see the result.

Comment: I have edited my solution, now it should work

Comment: i"vejust turtle instaled anymore mst be install?

Answer (score 0):

It won't do anything because you aren't calling anything.

```
draw_art()
```

Just add this at the end of your code.

Comment: Does it give you any errors or warnings ? @Kurniyandafitri

Comment: Can edit your question with what are you running as of now ?

Comment: so i've tried and add the function, i dont know why turtle still doesnt draw, no eror detected, this my 1st trial turtle program...any script or link must be install?

Comment: Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
======================== RESTART: D:\Program py\Draw.py ========================
>>>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the screen and haven't called the functions so it might be the problem.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, color, right, speed

def draw_square(some_turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(90)
    
def draw_art():
    brad = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.pensize(2)
    brad.speed(0)
    for _ in range(36):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)
    # Turtle Angie
    angie = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.pensize(2)
    angie.speed(0)
    size = 1
    for _ in range(300):
        angie.forward(size)
        angie.right(91)
        size += 1

timmy = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

draw_square(timmy)
draw_art()
```